# how can i add multiple ajax task on same page

Tags: ajax

How can I use multiple ajax in one page.
When I click on one button it calls one function and when I click on other button it calls another function.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous, the default behavior is not to block the execution of scripts by the means of ajax request. So you already can do what you are asking.